# Error when importing XLS into SAS 9.4

Tags: excel, ms-office, sas

In SAS 9.4 when going to the File > Import Data > Microsoft Excel Workbook, I get the following error:

> The SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files is not installed. Please install
>   this module in order to IMPORT/EXPORT to these file types.

However, it is installed per the following command:

```
proc setinit; run;

Operating System:   WX64_WKS.
Product expiration dates:

<snip>
---SAS/ACCESS Interface to DB2
         30JUN2014
---SAS/ACCESS Interface to Oracle
         30JUN2014
---SAS/ACCESS Interface to Sybase
         30JUN2014
---SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files
         30JUN2014
<end snip>
```

I had read that if I'm using 64-bit SAS then I need 64-bit MS Office, which is the case.

Suggestions?

Cheers, Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out our installer was incomplete or truncated, and despite going through the installation process, and saying it was going to install ACCESS PC, etc, it didn't.

With the updated installer all is now good.

Thanks for all your suggestions and help!

Answer (score 1):

Just because something is in your license -- what PROC SETINIT reads -- does not mean it was installed.  Launch the installer, add items to existing installation, and select ACCESS PC Files.

I don't have a 9.4 install to work with or I could give you exact prompts.

Comment: You are right. I've since learned there is a SAS macro that reveals what you're licensed for and what is installed: http://support.sas.com/kb/20/390.html Once I figure out what is amiss I'll update that info here. I'm guessing our installer is incomplete since it is 10GB where SAS 9.3 installer was 25GB

Answer (score 0):

You might try running proc import with `DBMS=xlsx`.  I'm not sure, but that may be installed if the ACE engine version importer (`excel` or the import menu) is not.